# Dual cone is a cone

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $E$ be a Banach space and $P$ be a cone. A nonempty convex closed set $P\subset E$ is called a cone if it satisfies the conditions: $x\in P,$ $\lambda \geq 0$ implies $\lambda x\in P$; $x\in P,$ $-x\in P$ implies $x=\theta$, where $\theta$ denotes the zero element of $E.$

A cone is said to be generating  if $E=P-P,$ i.e. every element $x\in E$ can be represented in the form $x=u-v,$ where $u,v\in P.$

The set $P^{*}=\left\{\psi \in E^{*}: \psi(x)\geq 0, \forall x\in P\right\}$ is called the dual cone of $P.$ $P^{*}$ satisfies all the conditions of a cone except $P^{*}\cap (-P^{*})=\left\{\theta\right\}$, and if P is generating, then all the conditions hold and $P^{*}$ is a cone of $E^{*}$.

Here, i could not prove how the dual cone satisfies the last condition of a cone when the cone $P$ is generating.
Note: this is not a homework question, so if the answer is clear I'd really be appreciated knowing why. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x^* \in P^*\cap (-P^*)$, that is $x^*, -x^* \in P^*$. Now let $x \in E$, as $P$ is generating, there are $u,v \in P$ such that $x = u-v$. Now
$$ x^*(x) = x^*(u) - x^*(v) = x^*(u) + (-x^*)(v) \ge 0 $$
But $x^*$ is linear, and $x$ was arbitrary, applying the above to $-x$, we get $x^*(-x) \ge 0$, hence $x^*(x) \le 0$. So $x^*(x) = 0$ for any $x$, that is $x^* = 0$.